# Is there any web service that could return all the routing number and their corresponding bank in the USA

Tags: web-services, banking

I need to get a API by which I could get all the routing number and their corresponding Bank name in the Americ

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about an open API, but this list is maintained by a lot of ACH providers and you should be able to access it.

This file is typically called the FED ACH directory, and lists the Bank Name, Routing Number, Address of each and every bank branch in the US.

I have a 2 year old copy, which you can [download from here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bymbmovwkyj05m0/FedACHdir.txt?dl=0) (its a text file)